# Chainlink functions implementation with args entered by user

Tags: chainlink

I'm using chainlink functions to make an http request to openai but the thing is that we need to enter the source, secrets again and again we send a request. Is there any way which requires only args to be send by user to make it more user friendly.

I also saw the automationConsumer contract but over there we made a CBOR which in which everthing including the args is fixed. But I want that the args must be input by user.

Comment: Hi Zumba, I don't know if you want users to input their own secrets or use your API key to make HTTP requests to openai for users. If you allow users to rely on your API to make HTTP request, the secrets are the same every time and you can write a script to save your secrets to be consumed by smart contract.